# Apple's answer to my app: App rejected because it crashed but I can't find the crash

Tags: ios, react-native, crash-reports

I received an App Submission Feedback from Apple:

> Thank you for your resubmission.
>
> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
>   attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device
>   to ensure it will launch without crashing.

I'm unable to find the crash reason, It seems like an unsymbolicated crash, which are often useless. My app doesn't crash when I test it, not even in release mode. It works perfectly in emulator as well as other real devices I have tested (Such as iPhone 4s, 5, 7 and also an iPad, iOS 9 and 10)

Here is the [crash log](https://codeshare.io/2p7qrY)
Please let me know if you have any idea what I can do to see what is the problem or if you know what is the problem, I would really appreciate your help, I can't submit my app to app store until this problem is resolved.

Note: The application was created with react native.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because developer centric questions about application stores are considered off topic here on SO, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835) meta answer by a moderator.

Comment: Apple sent you a crash log. Symbolicate it and see where the problem is.

Comment: You can symbolicate your own crash logs. Without that we're not going to have enough information to offer a useful answer here.

Comment: Crash seems to be around facebook library usage... are you asking any permission at startup where app would crash without it? Have you tested your app in flight mode? I'm not 100% certain about this but it's something for a starting.

Comment: Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue that's what caused your app crashed, I'm guessing it has something to do with the facebook sdk..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and rejected 2 time. My app created by React Native and have Facebook Login using FBSDK. It work fine on iOS Simulator and Testflight, but Apple reject and said it crash on startup up, they unable to test. 
On the first time, i'm just rebuild, increase the version, submit again, and Apple accept it. 
The second time is just yesterday and going to submit again.